# Fetch single array from multiple

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular6

I am making angular application where i am making a `forEach` function with service inside like,

```
   this.data.forEach(function(element) => {
      this.appService.getRest(element.optionsUrl, localStorage.getItem('token')).subscribe(result => {
           element.options = result.data;
           this.getIntake(this.data);
         });
    });
```

here i am trying to store the result comes from service to the `element.options` and then i am calling a function to get back the `data` value filled with `element.options` because from the service only i will get the value for `options` so after that i need to send this data to a function and need to retrieve it..

`result.data` is an array and it gives the following, `[{"id":1,"name":"option1"}]`,`[{"id":2,"name":"option2"}]`,`[{"id":3,"name":"option3"}]` respectively for three..

In `this.getIntake(data);` function if i `console.log(data)`

```
getIntake(data) {
 console.log(data);
}
```

then it is giving same array multiple times with same values like..

```
[
{"name":"abc", value: "abc", optionUrl: "abcUrl", options: [{"id":1,"name":"option1"}]},
{"name":"def", value: "def", optionUrl: "defUrl", options: [{"id":2,"name":"option2"}]},
{"name":"ghi", value: "ghi", optionUrl: "ghiUrl",  options: [{"id":3,"name":"option3"}]}
]


[
{"name":"abc", value: "abc", optionUrl: "abcUrl", options: [{"id":1,"name":"option1"}]},
{"name":"def", value: "def", optionUrl: "defUrl", options: [{"id":2,"name":"option2"}]},
{"name":"ghi", value: "ghi", optionUrl: "ghiUrl",  options: [{"id":3,"name":"option3"}]}
]

[
{"name":"abc", value: "abc", optionUrl: "abcUrl", options: [{"id":1,"name":"option1"}]},
{"name":"def", value: "def", optionUrl: "defUrl", options: [{"id":2,"name":"option2"}]},
{"name":"ghi", value: "ghi", optionUrl: "ghiUrl",  options: [{"id":3,"name":"option3"}]}
]
```

As the `data` has three objects, it was reflected three times..

For each object has element.optionsUrl and i need to subscribe that and need to store the data in element.options and if i came out of the service i am not getting the value in options and so i am making a function inside service and passing `this.data` with `options` to it.. In that function i am getting the data with values but i need to get completely filled data only once but it gives three as the data has three objects.. From that how to get the final only one array with filled data instead of three.

**Stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwvjqu

As the service is delayed i am making the function call on run time of the service and sending the data..

How to get only one array from this multiple generated array using pure angular/typescript, javascript way??

Comment: you could make a `Set()` which would not allow for duplicates. Not sure if there needs to be the ability to create duplicate data or not though...

Comment: why you are logging the entire array for each element in the array?

Comment: If i come out of the service then i am losing the stored data for options and so i am  making call inside the service..

Comment: Why do you iterate over it and not pass whole array inside it?

Comment: @Justcode, I am iterating ```this.data``` and in that i am having ```optionUrl``` from which i will get the data for ```options``` and so i am making service call inside forEach.. If i come out of service, i am unable to get the data and so passing it inside the service call.. So the options value will be set inside service and so i am trying to send ```this.data``` inside ```this.getIntake(this.data)``` function and trying to get and it is known that it will return three.. From which how can i get only one.. Is there any alternative please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are firing the request inside the `forEach` for each element in your array, it will subscribe for that many times, hence you see it logs 3 times.

**RxJS to help.**

Instead of loop through your `Array` with `forEach` use `from`, it converts your `Array` into an array of `Observable` and you can then do things with it, like fire a `http` request.

```
from(this.data)  //Converts your data array to array of Observables
.pipe(
    mergeMap(element => {
        return this.appService.getRest(element.optionsUrl, localStorage.getItem('token')) //fires http request for each element
        .pipe(
            map((result) => {  //change the data
                element.options = result.data;
                return of(element); //returns an observable for each element
            })
        )
    }),
    combineAll() //combines all the observable into one
)
.subscribe(x=>{
    this.getIntake(x); //x contains an array of your element
});
```

Comment: Can i have stackblitz like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-await-angular-demo-ae24ur with service call.. It would be helpful if you implement your solution by modifying the above stackblitz..